# Relational Algebra Queries look same

Tags: relational-algebra

[image: Relational Algebra Queries look same]

Query A and Query C seem to be the same.But given answer is query A.
Can someone help me to find the difference between queries A and C ?

Comment: Please consider including a textual version of the exercise. Images make it harder for people to find the question in searches, and are inadequate for people with visual impairments.

Comment: Not every assignment in a CS course or class is [on-topic, here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Without information about the *data model*, your question will be hard to answer no matter where, starting with uniqueness of supplier names.

Answer (score 0):

Because the id and the name fields are produced by the inner projections, this forces the  supplier supplying some red part and the supplier supplying some green part to be the same person in each case, not just any people with the same name.

This is why alternative A is correct, and alternative C is not.